# SaveFileDialog save the file after selecting image(by double click)

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to save the image in specific location. Bypassing "Confirm Save As, Do you want to replace it" popup.

```
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        string path = "C:\\MyDocs\\TimeIn&Out\\EmployeesPhoto";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = (@"C:\");
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Select Image";
        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".png";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
        saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = false;

        if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //path = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            //pictureBox1.Image.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            // I tried this 2 but not working
        }
    }
```

after clicking picturebox1=>after selecting image in a directory=> then it must be save the image in "path". But it shows this popup.

Comment: What do you mean by save image in path? Do you want to save it to a folder or a file?

Comment: i want to save it the folder. path is the directory that i declare

Comment: So why are you using a `SaveFileDialog` and not a `FolderBrowserDialog`?

Comment: because if i want to select an image after clicking picturebox, then it will automatically save in path = "C:\\MyDocs\\TimeIn&Out\\EmployeesPhoto";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the property:

```
saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = false;
```

should prevent the overwrite warning. I have no idea why it is not working for you, but you can use `openFileDialog` instead and then save the file by yourself if you like:

```
string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
if (File.Exists(path)){
    File.Delete(path);
}

using (FileStream fs = File.Create(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {
    fs.Write(imageFile, 0, info.Length);
}
```

**EDIT** So you actually want to allow the user to select an image, which you then want to save it to a specific folder with a specific name. You're code is not doing any of that. The purpose of the `SaveFileDialog` dialog is to save files, not to select ones. Use `OpenFileDialog` to allow your users to select the image file and then save the file by yourself. Similar to the code above, but with different logic:

```
Stream myStream = null;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\" ;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Image";
openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".png";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";

if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    try {
        string path = string path = @"C:\MyDocs\TimeIn&Out\EmployeesPhoto" + browseFileDialog1.FileName;
        if (File.Exists(path)) {
            File.Delete(path);
        }

        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null) {
            using (myStream) {
                using (var fs = File.Create(browseFileDialog1.FileName)) {
                    myStream.CopyTo(fs);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk.");
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the image i select is at "Desktop" and after selecting it will save automatically/programatically to "My Documents" folder

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? I thought you're saving the image from `pictureBox1`, aren't you? The `BrowseFolderDialog will allow you to choose where to save it to.

Comment: picturebox1 is just a control for clicking(it can also be a button). Best example is "facebook profile photo uploading". or "please upload photo" functionality.

Comment: So you want to select an existing image file and then save it somewhere else? That's not what your code is doing. Why are you using the `SaveFileDialog`? Do you want to allow the user to select where to save the image or do you want to save it to a specific folder with a specific name?

Comment: 1) So you want to select an existing image file and then save it somewhere else? Yes, save it somewhere. 2)i want to save it to a specific folder with a specific name after selection.